# Best practices for talking to an API

Tags: haskell, arguments

I'm trying to create some bindings for an API in Haskell. I noticed some functions have a tremendous number of arguments, e.g.

```
myApiFunction :: Key -> Account -> Int -> String -> Int -> Int -> IO (MyType)
```

It's not necessarily bad, per se, to have this many arguments. But as a user  I don't like long argument functions. However, each of these args is absolutely 100% necessary.

Is there a more haskell-ish way to abstract over the common parts of these functions? Everything past account here is used to build a URL, so I would need it available, and what it stands for depends entirely on the function. Certain things are consistent though, like `Key` and `Account`, and I'm wondering what the best to abstract over these arguments is.

Thank you!

Comment: Declare a type that bundles all these separate arguments up into one value? (Trying to find logical groupings is usually the fun part.) You may also want to define a `newtype` or at least a `type` alias for all those `Int` values.

Comment: I tried a bunch of different ideas in Strive, my API binding to Strava. I ultimately ended up with settings types and lenses. Check out [this issue](https://github.com/tfausak/strive/issues/44) for some discussion and [this example](https://github.com/tfausak/strive/tree/v1.0.1#segment-leaderboard) for how it looks now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine these into more descriptive data types:

```
data Config = Config
    { cKey :: Key
    , cAccount :: Account
    }
```

Then maybe have `type`s or `newtypes` to make the other arguments more descriptive:

```
-- I have no idea what these actually should be, I'm just making up something
type Count = Int
type Name = String
type Position = (Int, Int)

myApiFunction :: Config -> Count -> Name -> Position -> IO MyType
myApiFunction conf count name (x, y) =
    myPreviousApiFunction (cKey conf)
                          (cAccount conf)
                          name
                          name
                          x
                          y
```

If the `Config` is always needed, then I would recommend working in a `Reader` monad, which you can easily do as

```
myApiFunction
    :: (MonadReader Config io, MonadIO io)
    => Count -> Name -> Position
    -> io MyType
myApiFunction count name (x, y) = do
    conf <- ask
    liftIO $ myPreviousApiFunction
                (cKey conf)
                (cAccount conf)
                name
                name
                x
                y
```

This uses the `mtl` library for monad transformers.  If you don't want to have to type that constraint over and over, you can also use the `ConstraintKinds` extension to alias it:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
...

type ApiCtx io = (MonadReader Config io, MonadIO io)

...

myApiFunction
    :: ApiCtx io
    => Count -> Location -> Position
    -> io MyType
myApiFunction ...
```

Depending on your specific application, you could also split it up into multiple function.  I've seen plenty of APIs before that had something like

```
withCount :: ApiCtx io => Count    -> io a -> io a
withName  :: ApiCtx io => Name     -> io a -> io a
withPos   :: ApiCtx io => Position -> io a -> io a

(&) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b

request :: ApiCtx io => io MyType
```

---

```
> :set +m   -- Multi-line input
> let r = request & withCount 1
|                 & withName "foo"
|                 & withPos (1, 2)
> runReaderT r (Config key acct)
```

These are just a handful of techniques, there are others out there as well but they generally start becoming more complex after this.  Others will have different preferences on how to do this, and I'm sure plenty would disagree with me on whether some of these are even good practice (specifically `ConstraintKinds`, it isn't universally accepted).

If you find yourself having type signatures that are too large a lot, even after applying some of these techniques, then maybe you're approaching the problem from the wrong direction, maybe those functions can be broken down into simpler intermediate steps, maybe some of those arguments can be grouped together logically into more specific data types, maybe you just need a larger record structure to handle setting up complex operations.  It's pretty open ended right now.

Comment: I love the last one. Thanks for all these

Comment: @Steve it takes a ReaderT action and the value to be returned from a call to ask, and then runs the action using that value. If you've used the State monad before then think of the Reader monad as a fixed state, you can only get it, not set it. It's often used to pass in static configuration.